# SELECT with two AND conditions

Tags: mysql

I want to use a `SELECT` statement in MySQL with two `AND` conditions. This is my table and insert, followed by the select statement. I do not get any result from the select statement.

```
-- 
-- Table structure for table `indextable`
-- 

CREATE TABLE `indextable` (
  `post_id` bigint(40) NOT NULL,
  `key` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `cat_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  KEY `key_2` (`key`),
  KEY `value_2` (`value`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- 
-- Dumping data for table `indextable`
-- 

INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (390, 'doors', '360', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (390, 'body_type', '347', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (390, 'seller_type', '11', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (390, 'mechanical_condition', '6', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (390, 'body_condition', '1', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (390, 'kilometers', '', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (390, 'year', '2012', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (390, 'mobile', '', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (390, 'price', '111111111111', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (388, 'city', 'localhost', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (388, 'description', '<!--:en-->dddddddddd', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (388, 'title', '<!--:en-->555       ', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (388, 'categories_name', 'Cars souq', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (388, 'images', 'http://localhost/wor', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (388, 'fuel_type', '380', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (388, 'warranty', '725', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (388, 'horsepower', '387', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (388, 'transmission_type', '377', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (388, 'color', '707', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (388, 'no_of_cylinders', '365', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (388, 'doors', '360', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (388, 'body_type', '347', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (388, 'seller_type', '11', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (388, 'mechanical_condition', '6', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (388, 'body_condition', '1', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (388, 'kilometers', '', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (388, 'year', '2012', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (388, 'mobile', '', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (388, 'price', '3333', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (390, 'no_of_cylinders', '365', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (390, 'color', '707', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (390, 'transmission_type', '377', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (390, 'horsepower', '387', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (390, 'warranty', '725', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (390, 'fuel_type', '380', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (390, 'images', '', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (390, 'categories_name', 'Cars souq', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (390, 'title', '<!--:en-->ddddddddd<', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (390, 'description', '<!--:en-->dddddddddd', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (390, 'city', 'localhost', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (392, 'price', '133', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (392, 'mobile', '', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (392, 'year', '2012', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (392, 'kilometers', '222', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (392, 'body_condition', '1', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (392, 'mechanical_condition', '6', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (392, 'seller_type', '11', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (392, 'body_type', '347', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (392, 'doors', '360', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (392, 'no_of_cylinders', '365', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (392, 'color', '707', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (392, 'transmission_type', '377', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (392, 'horsepower', '387', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (392, 'warranty', '725', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (392, 'fuel_type', '380', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (392, 'images', '', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (392, 'categories_name', 'Cars souq', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (392, 'title', '<!--:en-->ddddddddd<', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (392, 'description', '<!--:en-->dddddddddd', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (392, 'city', 'localhost', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (393, 'price', '111111111111', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (393, 'mobile', '', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (393, 'year', '2012', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (393, 'kilometers', '', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (393, 'body_condition', '1', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (393, 'mechanical_condition', '6', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (393, 'seller_type', '11', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (393, 'body_type', '347', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (393, 'doors', '360', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (393, 'no_of_cylinders', '365', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (393, 'color', '707', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (393, 'transmission_type', '377', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (393, 'horsepower', '387', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (393, 'warranty', '725', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (393, 'fuel_type', '380', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (393, 'images', '', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (393, 'categories_name', 'Cars souq', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (393, 'title', '<!--:en-->ddddddddd<', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (393, 'description', '<!--:en-->dddddddddd', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (393, 'city', 'localhost', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (398, 'price', '11333', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (398, 'mobile', '', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (398, 'year', '2012', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (398, 'kilometers', '', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (398, 'body_condition', '1', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (398, 'mechanical_condition', '6', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (398, 'seller_type', '11', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (398, 'body_type', '347', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (398, 'doors', '360', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (398, 'no_of_cylinders', '365', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (398, 'color', '707', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (398, 'transmission_type', '377', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (398, 'horsepower', '387', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (398, 'warranty', '725', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (398, 'fuel_type', '380', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (398, 'images', 'http://localhost/wor', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (398, 'categories_name', 'Cars souq', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (398, 'title', '<!--:en-->aaaaaaaaaa', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (398, 'description', '<!--:en-->aaaaaaaaaa', 398);
INSERT INTO `indextable` VALUES (398, 'city', 'localhost', 398);

SELECT distinct post_id FROM indextable as i WHERE ( i.key ='price' AND i.value BETWEEN 12 AND 1000 ) AND ( i.key ='year' AND i.value=2012 )
```

Notice: when I use only the first condition or only the second condition I get a result.

I want to execute a query like this:

```
SELECT distinct post_id 
FROM indextable as i 
WHERE ( i.key ='price' AND i.value BETWEEN 12 AND 1000 )
    AND ( i.key ='year' AND i.value=2012 )
    AND ( i.key ='body_condition' AND i.value=1 )
    AND ( i.key ='mechanical_condition' AND i.value=6 )
    AND ( i.key ='seller_type' AND i.value=11 )
    AND ( i.key ='body_type' AND i.value=347 )
    AND ( i.key ='doors' AND i.value=360 )
    AND ( i.key ='no_of_cylinders' AND i.value=365 )
    AND ( i.key ='color' AND i.value=707 )
    AND ( i.key ='transmission_type' AND i.value=377 )
    AND ( i.key ='horsepower' AND i.value=387 )
    AND ( i.key ='warranty' AND i.value=725 )
    AND ( i.key ='fuel_type' AND i.value=380 )
```

Comment: Works as designed, doesn't it? There are no records that match both conditions at once. You are probably looking for `OR` instead of `AND`?

Comment: @user1431393 as how I said you need to change the ...) AND (... for OR, so it will be (....) OR (....) OR (...) or .....

Answer (score 1):

that's because your condition it's wrong.

```
    SELECT distinct post_id FROM indextable as i 
WHERE ( i.key ='price' AND i.value BETWEEN 12 AND 1000 ) 
AND ( i.key ='year' AND i.value=2012 )
```

that's the same that use

```
    SELECT distinct post_id FROM indextable as i 
WHERE  i.key ='price' AND i.value BETWEEN 12 AND 1000 
AND  i.key ='year' AND i.value=2012
```

I think what you try to do is

```
    SELECT distinct post_id FROM indextable as i 
WHERE ( i.key ='price' AND i.value BETWEEN 12 AND 1000 ) 
OR ( i.key ='year' AND i.value=2012 )
```

EDIT: what you mean you don't have this results? I copy your table and did the queries and it works.

[image]

Comment: I don't have any result when I using this statment:

Comment: I used " and " so that i don't have any result but when i used or i have like ur result ,I think with or the proplem will be solve :)thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 .... WHERE ( i.key ='price' AND i.value BETWEEN 12 AND 1000 ) AND 
            ( i.key ='year' AND i.value=2012 )
```

means that the value of i.key has to be 'price' and 'year' in the same row. That's impossible, hence no result!

Change to

```
 .... WHERE ( i.key ='price' AND i.value BETWEEN 12 AND 1000 ) OR 
            ( i.key ='year' AND i.value=2012 )
```

Comment: I want all advertisment from database where price is between 12 and 1000 and years is 2012...u suggest to me using or insted of and?Ok thnx for u very much